# C++ error : 'does not name a type error '

Tags: c++

When runs this program ,compiler gives a error saying that "**varA**(in class C)does not name a type".what's the wrong with me?explain plz.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
private:
    int PrvA1;
public:
     A(){PrvA1=0;}
    void SetPrvA1(int x){PrvA1=x;}
    int show(){return PrvA1;}
};

class C{
    A varA;
    varA.SetPrvA1(20);
    public:
    void show(){
            cout<<varA.show()<<endl;
    }

};

int main(){
    A a1;
    C c1;
    a1.SetPrvA1(30);
    cout<<a1.show()<<endl;
    c1.show();
}
```

Comment: You can't have `varA.SetPrvA1(20);` outside a function body. You did it right for `A`.

Comment: If you need to initialize a member variable you need a constructor.

Comment: that is can't call a function of a class outside of a function?@A

Comment: ***that is can't call a function of a class outside of a function?*** Correct. You can't put arbitrary code outside a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize directly in the class without method(or constructor) ,change in to

```
class C{
    A varA;
    
    public:
    C(){ varA.SetPrvA1(20);}
    void show(){
            cout<<varA.show()<<endl;
    }

};
```